# Could not connect to PostgreSql Server (computer) from a client (Raspberry PI)

Tags: networking, server, ssh, 22.04, postgresql

I followed the instructions as: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/databases-postgresql
This is what I did:

**Postgresql-server (On my Ubuntu desktop computer)**

```
# Installed the Postgresql server 
# Went to the sudo nano /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf 
# entered following line at end: 
# My understanding of below line is allow the connection to the  
# this ubuntu computer (10.1.2.3) from a 
# remote device with ip 10.1.2.4 with user postgres
hostssl template1       postgres        10.1.2.4            scram-sha-256

# This device ip on which Postgresql server is sitting: 10.1.2.3
```

**Postgresql-client (On the remote Raspberry PI device)** (ip: 10.1.2.4):
This is what I did:

```
# Install Postgresql-client 
# access the Postgresql-server as 
psql --host 10.1.2.3 --username postgres --password --dbname template1
```

**Present output on the Postgresql-client**:

```
psql error: could not connect to server: connection refused
             Is the server running on host 10.1.2.3 and accepting 
             TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

First time I heard about this port 5432. I would like to know what is wrong and how to rectify it?

**Update**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

we tried to replicate your pg_hba.conf entry:

```
hostssl template1       postgres        10.1.2.4            scram-sha-256
```

and we encountered postgresql server errors at restart in /var/log/syslog, a line like:

```
LOG:  invalid IP mask "scram-sha-256": Name or service not known
```

which reminded us that we are missing the "IP-Mask" after the "AP-Address". Please add "/32" mask at the end of 10.1.2.4 address, like here:

```
hostssl template1       postgres        10.1.2.4/32         scram-sha-256
```

and postgresql server may be restarted with success.